# Proof about Lagrange's theorem in number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Based on the textbook Lagrange's theorem states: The congruence $$f(x) \equiv 0\pmod p$$

in which $$f(x)=a_0x^n+....+a_n,\text{ } a_0\not\equiv0\pmod p$$

has at most $n$ roots. $p$ is a prime number .

Question: Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, with integral coefficients. Show that if $n+1$ consecutive values of $f(x)$ are divisible by a fixed prime $p$, then $p\mid f(x)$ for every integral $x$.

Approach: We have to consider the cases in which $p\le n+1$ and $p>n+1$

if $p\le n+1$ then the problem is very easy. We can create a complete residue system $\pmod p$ and say for every integer $x$ there exists an integer $y$ in the complete residue system such that $p\mid x-y$ which would lead to the conclusion that $p\mid f(x)-f(y)$ and therefore $p\mid f(x)$.
The problem is when $p>n+1$ and I think we have to use Lagrange's theorem as it's part of the chapter I am reading.
If it's possible, try to use my version of Lagrange's theorem when you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $p\gt n+1$, then the $n+1$ consecutive values are distinct modulo $p$. Thus $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at least $n+1$ distinct solutions modulo $p$.

By Lagrange's Theorem, it follows that all the coefficients of $f$ are divisible by $p$. If we look at Lagrange's Theorem exactly as stated, then we can only conclude that $a_0\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. But then the polynomial congruence $f(x)-a_0x^n\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has too many solutions, so $a_1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, and so on.

Comment: Ok let's analyze what you say sentence by sentence. In the first sentence you say if $p>n+1$, then $n+1$ consecutive values are distinct modulo p. How is that true?. I think n+1-p integers have to be the same mod p. Nevermind what I said

Comment: @TheMathNoob:  Let $a$ and $b$ be two of the $n+1$ consecutive  values, where $a\lt b$. Then $0\lt b-a\le n$. Since $p\gt n$, it follows that $p$ cannot divide $b-a$, so $a\not\equiv b\pmod{p}$, meaning that $a$ and $b$ are distinct modulo $p$.

Comment: Yes, now why is the following true, "Thus $f(x)\equiv 0(mod$ $ p)$" has at least n+1 distinct solutions modulo p?

Comment: @TheMathNoob: We are told that for consecutive values $x=a,a+1,\dots,a+n$, $p$ divides $f(x)$. So $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ holds for (at least) $n+1$ pairwise incongruent values of $x$ modulo $p$. Thus the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at least $n+1$ solutions.

Comment: how do we conclude $a_0 \equiv 0(mod$ $ p)$ if it's stated in the theorem that it's not.

Comment: The theorem says that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $a_0$ **not** divisible by $p$, then the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has **at most** $n$ solutions. Our polynomial has degree $n$, and we have found that $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has **more than** $n$ incongruent solutions modulo $p$. So the condition $a_0\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ must fail. If it did not fail, our $\ge n+1$ solutions would contradict Lagrange;s Theorem.

Comment: ok so at the end w conclude $a_n \equiv 0(mod$ $ p)$. How does that imply $f(x) \equiv 0(mod$ $ p))$ for all integral x?

Comment: At the end we conclude that all the coefficients of $f(x)$ are divisible by $p$. If $a_k\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for all $k$, then $a_0b^n+a_1b^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for any $b$.

Comment: You are welcome. Another (equivalent) version of Lagrange's Theorem says precisely this. If the the degree $n$ polynomial has more than $n$ roots modulo $p$, then all the coefficients are divisible by $p$. It will all look neater, and perhaps a little clearer, when this material is stated in the language of fields, but the author has chosen not to do so. The key thing is that the objects $0,1,\dots,p-1$ under addition and multiplication mod $p$ form a field. In any field $F$, a polynomial of degree $n$ can have no more than $n$ roots.

Comment: I just have one more inquiry. The problem says that $p|f(x)$ for $n+1$ consecutive integers. How do we know that $p|f(x)-a_0x^n$ for $n+1$ consecutive integers.

Comment: Since $p$ divides $a_0$, any solution of $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ is also a solution of $f_1(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, where $f_1(x)=f(x)-a_0x^n$.

Comment: mmmm it's still hard for me to see why if the number of solutions is n+1 then that would imply $a_0 \equiv 0(mod$ $ p)$. I am still confused with polynomials being congruent for example in this case $f(x) \equiv 0(mod$ $ p)$ would mean two things. For so. me values x, the latter holds. It would also mean that polynomials are algebraically congruent. It would be good if you explain how you from my version to your version of the theorem

Comment: Well, for that we need to go through a proof of Lagrange's Theorem. It is true that there is a big difference between *polynomial functions* and *polynomials*. In the familiar case of polynomials with real coefficients, if $f$ and $g$ are the .same as *functions*, then they are the same as polynomials. This is not true in finite fields. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) For example, $x^p-x$ is, by Fermat's theorem, identically $0$ as a function from the field of $p$ elements to the field of $p$ elements. But $x^p-x$ and $0$ are different as polynomials. In the language you used they are not algebraically congruent.  Of course if two polynomials, like $x^2+2px+p$ and $x^2$, are algebraically congruent, they determine the same function.